# How to make a Container widget to an ExpansionPanelList widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my container widget with decorations

```
Container(
    height: 90,
    width: 150,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.grey,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black,
          offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
          blurRadius: 14.0,
          spreadRadius: -15,
        ), //BoxShadow
      ],
    ),
  );
```

I need to perform `ExpansionPanelList` with the same decoration

[image]

but when I'm doing this, then this happening

[image]

how do I make this inside of the container?
or how do I make the expansion panel widget to this style?

here is my expansion list code

```
ExpansionPanelList.radio(
        children: taskList
            .map((task) => ExpansionPanelRadio(
                  value: task,
                  headerBuilder: (context, isOpen) =>
                      TaskTile(task: task, taskList: taskList),
                  body: const Text('ss'),
                ))
            .toList());
```

the `TaskTile` is task tile widget that contains the widgets inside the expansion panel

how do I implement this?

Comment: Can you include sample `ExpansionPanelList` on your widget?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh done please check

Comment: Now I think last one is better, try [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is this looks like you want the expanded list:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Expansion Panel List';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// stores ExpansionPanel state information
class Item {
  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.expandedValue,
    required this.headerValue,
    this.checkValue = false,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });
  int id;
  String expandedValue;
  String headerValue;
  bool isExpanded;
  bool checkValue;
}

List<Item> generateItems(int numberOfItems) {
  return List<Item>.generate(numberOfItems, (int index) {
    return Item(
      id: index,
      headerValue: 'Panel $index',
      expandedValue: 'This is item number $index',
    );
  });
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  final List<Item> _data = generateItems(8);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
              blurRadius: 14.0,
              spreadRadius: -15,
            ), //BoxShadow
          ],
        ),
        child: _buildPanel(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      initialOpenPanelValue: 1,
      children: _data.map<ExpansionPanel>((Item item) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
          value: item.id,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Row(
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        // Toggle check value when tapped.
                        item.checkValue = !item.checkValue;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                        item.checkValue ? Icons.check_box : Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded,
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text(item.headerValue,
                  style: TextStyle(decoration: item.checkValue ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
          body: ListTile(
              title: Text(item.expandedValue),
              subtitle:
              const Text('To delete this panel, tap the trash can icon'),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _data.removeWhere((Item currentItem) => item == currentItem);
                });
              }),
          // isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

If you want to add more items i.e date you can do that by adding it in TaskFile class and for style you can also do that in that class, If you want padding in the Expanded List, then, give the form of the list as you want.

Answer (score 0):

i've a simmilar issue before when i was creating a Flutter app, then i realized that is more efficient, using MediaQuery instead giving numbers, i.e.

```
height:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*10,
width:  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*80,
```

this is a example, i hope that you can solve this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry the problem is not the overflow . i want to make the container that I showed first is to be an expansion panel